# How to stub MQ response ?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, message, ibm-mq

As part of new development, we are integrating with external system, which is still in the development phase. In order to test our own code, how can we stub External system response so we don't end up in surprise when the actual Integration starts? We have the agreed mapping formats.

Any thoughts around the Best Practices would be great.

- Message Type : XML
- Communication : IBM MQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mq transport will consist of you sending requests on one queue and receiving responses on another, you simply create an external process that consumes from your request queue, approximates a response and sends a response back on the response queue.